# getopts does not recognize question mark

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, getopts

I am currently parsing options in a script like that:

```
while getopts ":ia" OptionArgument; do
case $OptionArgument in
    i ) echo "bli";;
    a ) echo "bla";;
    * ) echo "flag not known";;
    ? ) echo "unknown parameter";;
esac
done
```

Every parsing option and flag works - except this one: `? )`. So if I call my script with something like `./MyScript hjrfgdskjgh` it passes the loop correctly - although it should be catched in the last line with `? )`. 

I also tried removing quotes from `":ia"`or using `\?` or `. )` - nothing works! What do I do wrong??

Comment: `* ) echo "flag not known";;` is doing what `?` would do. If you comment `*) ...` you will get `?)` working.

Comment: Both don't work: the `* )` only parses unknown flags, such as e.g. -x or -y. But it ignores random words like `kajdhkjefhskef`. If I remove `* )` or replace`it with `? )` because of the order - nothing changes. It's like it doesn't know `?` at all...

Comment: `getopts` will handle any flag *that has a - in the beginning*. If you execute `./script -t` it will show `flag not known`, but if you do `./script t` it is like you are not giving info to `getopts`.

Comment: Ah now I understand: so if I don't use the dash `-` it doesn't get it at all. I thought getopts could handle this as well, but in this case I must check this manually. Thanks a lot, if you add it as answer, I'll mark this as correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

`?` character has a special meaning, see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#WILDCARDQU  You can't use it unescaped or unquoted.  You have to call the script with `./script.sh -'?'` or `./script.sh -\?`

Comment: Technically correct, but the default behavior is to treat patterns that don't match anything literally. You only need to escape the `?` if there are files with `-`-initial, 2-character names in the current directory (which should rarely happen).

Comment: @chepner that's true in bash but not in all shells, e.g. `zsh`.  A portable script should consider this.

Comment: The POSIX standard specifies that an unmatched pattern be treated literally. `zsh` users should probably use `setopt NONOMATCH` to conform to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

`*` matches anything. Putting anything below it is meaningless, it would only be matched if the `*` does not match it.

Comment: Even if I remove this line and just add the line with the question mark instead - it doesn't catch the random wrong parameter. As if it doesn't recognize the `?`at all.